# how to calculate effective annual rate if it's calculated once in 3 years?

Tags: economics

Interest rate is $9\%$ a year, but it's calculated once every $3$ years. How to calculate the effective annual rate?

The formula I know is:

$$r = \left(1 + \dfrac in\right)^n - 1,$$

where $n$ is the period, which is $3$ years, and $i$ = $9\%$ interest rate.

I'm confused.

Comment: What do you mean by, "It's calculated once in $3$ years?"  Please give an example of how interest is charged.  The formula you give would be appropriate if interest were compounded three times a year.

Comment: Just use the simple interest which leads to $i_{\textrm{eff}}\approx 8.3\%$